Sharepoint Event web part
I'm working on a SharePoint web part page for my organization and have encountered a few challenges.

Is there a way to switch the Calendar view to a list format, similar to an Outlook calendar layout, on the default page?

I'm trying to add a dropdown menu to the default page but have been unsuccessful so far.

Lastly, I would like to replace a "see all" link in the default page link with a custom URL but am having trouble doing so.


Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you
